# Why RecyclerView adapter for ViewPager2?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-viewpager2

Why do we use `RecyclerView` adapter for the `ViewPager2`? Why doesn't it use its own class for the adapter? I see `ViewPager2`'s class and it does not extend or do anything with reycler view. Then why `RecyclerView`'s adapter?

Comment: RecyclerView has performance improvements over typical listviews, so now it's used for every kind of list

Comment: Original `ViewPager` was a "standalone" container that used its own adapter, entire touch handling and page flipping logic. It was deprecated as that approach was deemed unmaintainable and pointless. Since `RecyclerView` is such a good way to handle lists `ViewPager2` wraps it and adds some custom listeners responsible for handling fragment lifecycles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because ViewPager2 is just a specialised container of a RecycyerView.

It's a bit hidden

But from the [code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/refs/heads/androidx-main/viewpager2/viewpager2/src/main/java/androidx/viewpager2/widget/ViewPager2.java#973)

```java
     private class RecyclerViewImpl extends RecyclerView {
        RecyclerViewImpl(@NonNull Context context) {
            super(context);
        }
```

and then in the [initialize](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/refs/heads/androidx-main/viewpager2/viewpager2/src/main/java/androidx/viewpager2/widget/ViewPager2.java#192) method of viewpager2

```java
private void initialize(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        mAccessibilityProvider = sFeatureEnhancedA11yEnabled
                ? new PageAwareAccessibilityProvider()
                : new BasicAccessibilityProvider();
        mRecyclerView = new RecyclerViewImpl(context);
```